# Loading pictures to gallery

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching

I need some advice. In my application people can upload images. I will store the images on a server. I want to make a photo gallery where you can see all uploaded images. Every user has a account. And it will download all uploaded images.

The point is that when you uploaded 1 image it has to download 1 image. But when you upload 10 or more the app will have to download all images and cache the images to your device.

What is the best way to download all images and keep the app running without getting stuck. Also what is the best way to cache all images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create some photo gallery apps, check out this open source [sample](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser).

Created by Michael Waterfall, which includes photo gallery from images stored on server or locally.

You can modify the code as per your project requirements. And it is easy to handle the images.